# Swift: TableView not scrolling with custom tab bar

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a custom tab bar which I disable click in a certain place

```
class UserTabBar: BaseTabBar {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.addShape(for: .user)
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 35
        return abs(self.center.x - point.x) > buttonRadius || abs(point.y) > buttonRadius
    }

}
```

But in a controller wrapped by the tab bar, there is a tableview and the scrolling does not work
How I can limit this only to the frame of the tab bar:

```
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 35
        return abs(self.center.x - point.x) > buttonRadius || abs(point.y) > buttonRadius
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my probleme by using:

```
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard !clipsToBounds && !isHidden && alpha > 0, path.contains(point) else { return nil }

        for member in subviews.reversed() {
            let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
            guard let result = member.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) else { continue }
            return result
        }

        return nil
    }
```